# Dual monitor is not working with nvidia-prime

Tags: 14.04, nvidia-prime, nvidia-settings

I have `ASUS K555LA` with optimus nvidia(740M). I have installed `nvidia-340`, `nvidia-prime` and everything is working just fine. Now `nvidia driver` is enable and my second monitor is just black(like no display signal). `Nvidia-settings` can't detect the second display. In display of system settings, i can see the 2nd monitor but can't enable it. It always hang or crash when i try to enable second monitor.

2nd monitor is working fine with `intel` driver. Previously i used `bumblebee` with `nvidia-340` and that was working fine. Now nvidia-prime can't handle secondary display. I didn't change any configuration of driver. Dual monitor is also working in login screen (`lightdm`) with `nvidia` driver.

## system info

```
Ubuntu 14.04 (64bit)
8 GB RAM
Nvidia 740M(hybrid)
Corei7
```

## xorg.conf

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier "layout"
    Screen 0 "nvidia"
    Inactive "intel"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "intel"
    Driver "intel"
    BusID "PCI:0@0:2:0"
    Option "AccelMethod" "SNA"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "intel"
    Device "intel"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    Driver "nvidia"
    BusID "PCI:4@0:0:0"
    Option "ConstrainCursor" "off"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    Device "nvidia"
    Option "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration" "on"
    Option "IgnoreDisplayDevices" "CRT"
EndSection
```

## nvidia driver version

```
server glx version string: 1.4
client glx version string: 1.4
GLX version: 1.4
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.3.0 NVIDIA 340.76
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.30 NVIDIA via Cg compiler
OpenGL version string: 4.4.0 NVIDIA 340.76
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.40 NVIDIA via Cg compiler 
nvidia-prime 0.6.2
```